# Integration testing with FubuMvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing, fubumvc

I was thinking that it would be great to have something like this:

```
var mvc = new MyFullyConfiguredFubuMvc();
var response1 = mvc.Request("http://myawesomewebsite.com/page1");
var response2 = mvc.Request(new StringRequest { 
    Url="http://myawesomewebsite.com/page1?q=asylum", 
    CookieName=".aspauth",CookieBody="x=5;y=9",
    Method="get",
    Headers="y:6; z:qwerty"
});
```

So the Q is: how easy will it be to make this with FubuMvc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example for you:
https://gist.github.com/4697920